# Windows QueryPerformanceCounter with MinGW C

Tags: c, performance, time, timer, mingw

I'm trying to measure my response time on a serial protocol handshake by pulling QueryPerformanceCounter (QPC). My target system is a win7 on Asrock D1800b Intel Dual Core, compiling with latest version of MinGw (6.3.0-1).

In order to test QPC I have this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() 
{
    //performance timers
    LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
    LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
        Sleep(10); //ms
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
        ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
        ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;                //first scale up counts
        ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;     //then convert to us
        printf("elapsed=%li\n", ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart);
    }

}
```

When run on the target system I get: (no other loads)

> elapsed=5341
>   elapsed=14086
>   elapsed=13818
>   elapsed=14322
>   elapsed=15305
>   elapsed=8867
>   elapsed=12162
>   elapsed=14225
>   elapsed=13333
>   elapsed=14751

But when run on the developing system (Win10, Intel i5), I get this much consistent result

> elapsed=11326
>   elapsed=11556
>   elapsed=12630
>   elapsed=11583
>   elapsed=11749
>   elapsed=12644
>   elapsed=12562
>   elapsed=11690
>   elapsed=11726
>   elapsed=11664

Both above results are examples of a much larger run.

the expected result is somewhere above 10000us.

So, any ideas of what it going on on the target system?

Comment: Is the target system experiencing some constant and fairly large load variations?

Comment: try with 50 ms. 10 ms is close to the limit of unreliability for the sleep method. Well, I guess that sleep is here for the example right?

Comment: Aside: note the compiler warning about the format type specifier in `printf`.

Comment: The bottom line here is that Windows is not a real time operating system, and has absolutely no pretensions about being one.  In particular `Sleep()` comes with no guarantees as to exactly how long it'll delay execution.  You'll get a best effort, but that's about it.  `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is fairly accurate, but if I might make an analogy, what you're doing here is akin to using a micrometer to measure the size of logs that were cut by hand with an axe.

Comment: I get windows not being a RTOS, but i had asummed that best effort on a Sleep will cause a longer wait, rather than a shorter one.

Comment: The goal of this example is to verify the Frecuency parameter of QPC, as the warning noted in this artice:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps

Comment: Comparison: Windows 7 on i3-3240 gives consistent results for the 10ms sleep (with only 1 value > 10000), 5ms sleep is similar, at 2ms the timing is erratic. Your system memory [bus speed](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/D1800B-ITX/) (1333) seems to be twice mine (667) and both are DDR3. So as commented perhaps your system has a lot to do.

Comment: Another comparison, Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Intel DP67BG motherboard, Intel 3770K 3.5ghz cpu, Sleep(10) returns on the next 64hz == 15.625 ms boundary. This is what I mention in my answer. I have to use [timeBeginPeriod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757633(v=vs.85).aspx). to speed up the tick rate in order for Sleep(10) to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to increase the tick rate, which may be defaulted to 64hz (15.625 ms per tick) in order to get Sleep(10) to work as expected. You can increase it to 1000hz (1 ms per tick). This will increase interrupt overhead, but results should be more consistent. Example code fragment:

```
    timeBeginPeriod(1);                     /* set ticker to 1000 hz */
    Sleep(128);                             /* wait for it to settle */
    /* ... benchmark code */
    timeEndPeriod(1);                       /* restore ticker to default */
```

Note, although Windows is not a real time OS, it is possible in Windows to get a thread to run at a fixed frequency without any drift, and using Sleep(1) when possible to avoid going cpu bound in the fixed frequency thread. Running the thread at a slightly higher priority will help if there are competing threads. This is often used by games that need a "physics engine" thread that runs at a fixed frequency. Example code is included in the answer to this old question:

[How to coordinate threads properly based on a fixed cycle frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323214/how-to-coordinate-threads-properly-based-on-a-fixed-cycle-frequency)

Example output from a program based on the example in the link, using a fixed frequency of 100hz, run 100 times. There's some variation in each step, but there is no overall drift.

```
 100 deltas in ms:

  9.99973023  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00676775  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00794067  10.00002346 
  9.99973023  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00618129  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346   9.99973023  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00090315  10.00148961  10.00148961  10.00090315 
 10.00002346  10.00178284  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00295576  10.00002346  10.00882036  10.00500837 
 10.00002346  10.00559483  10.00559483  10.00647452 
 10.00588806  10.00735421  10.00676775  10.00764744 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00823390  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346   9.99973023  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346   9.99973023 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346   9.99973023 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 
 10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346  10.00002346 

elapsed time in ms:

1000.000000000000
```

Comment: I see your point, but this thread has little to do with Sleep accuracy but to understand its relation to QPC.
The best i have so far is thar windows may choose not to put a lower threshold for the Sleep call, just to make a best effort for accomplishing the time.
Thank you so much for your help.